# IQueryable<> from stored procedure (entity framework)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I want to get `IQueryable<>` result when executing stored procedure.

Here is piece of code that works fine:

```
IQueryable<SomeEntitiy> someEntities;  
var globbalyFilteredSomeEntities = 
  from se in m_Entities.SomeEntitiy
    where
      se.GlobalFilter == 1234 
  select se;
```

I can use this to apply global filter, and later use the result in something like:

```
result = globbalyFilteredSomeEntities
  .OrderByDescending(se => se.CreationDate)
  .Skip(500)
  .Take(10);
```

---

What I want to do - use some stored procedures in global filter.
I tried:

Add stored procedure to `m_Entities`, but it returns `IEnumerable<>` and executes sp immediately:

```
var globbalyFilteredSomeEntities = 
  from se in m_Entities.SomeEntitiyStoredProcedure(1234);
```

Materialize query using EFExtensions library, but it is `IEnumerable<>`.
If I use `AsQueryable()` and `OrderBy()`, `Skip()`, `Take()`
and after that `ToList()` to execute that query -
I get exception that `DataReader` is open and I need to close it first(can't paste error - it is in russian).

```
var globbalyFilteredSomeEntities = 
  m_Entities.CreateStoreCommand("exec SomeEntitiyStoredProcedure(1234)")
            .Materialize<SomeEntitiy>();
            //.AsQueryable()
            //.OrderByDescending(se => se.CreationDate)
            //.Skip(500)
            //.Take(10)
            //.ToList();
```

Also just skipping `.AsQueryable()` is not helpful - same exception.
When I put `ToList()` query executes,
but it is too expensive to execute query without `Skip()`, `Take()`.

Comment: Is this EF 4? If so, use `ExecuteStoreQuery`, and then you won't need `Materialize`.

Comment: No, it is EF 1, but if `ExecuteStoreQuery` resolves my problem I will consider moving to EF4. Can you share links to some special articles about that(if you have ones).

Comment: I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201369/entity-framework-objectcontext-executestorequery-produces-detached-objects and it is stated that `ExecuteStoreQuery` returns `ObjectResult` collection - same as `m_Entities.SomeEntitiyStoredProcedure(1234);`. So seems that `ExecuteStoreQuery` will not resolve my problem.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. This (`Take()`...) won't be possible, because if *you* write the SQL, the EF cannot further compose that SQL. However, if you *do* use `ExecuteStoreQuery` then you *can* use `TOP` and the like in the SQL that you write.

Comment: Did `ExecuteStoreQuery` return `ObjectResult` or it return `ObjectQuery`? If it returns `ObjectResult` - it is unusable for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do, for the same reason that you can't put a stored procedure in a FROM clause of a SELECT query - SQL isn't built to support this kind of operation.

Could you put the logic you want into a view instead of a stored procedure?

Comment: Nice idea. Will EF return same type of entity from the view, or I have to do some more steps to achieve that? Cane you share some code snippet working with view in ef?

Comment: Without EF, there is no problem doing what he wants to, though.

Comment: Would be nice to see usage example of Database View in EF. I'm not interested doing it without EF.

Comment: Support for table-valued functions has been added in .NET 4.5 and EF5. Change your stored proc into a TVF and you can use the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16811388/175157).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a project I created called [LinqToAnything](https://github.com/mcintyre321/LinqToAnything) which lets you take a non-queryable data access method and turn it into an IQueryable.

I've got a blog post [here](http://ghosttenprinthello.azurewebsites.net/creating-an-iqueryable-for-a-stored-proc-or-web-service-using-linqtoanything/) on how to use it.

Answer (score -3):

sually you can get around these issues with ToList()

```
var globbalyFilteredSomeEntities = m_Entities.CreateStoreCommand("exec SomeEntitiyStoredProcedure(1234)") 
                                             .Materialize<SomeEntitiy>()
                                             .ToList()  // <<-- added this.
                                             .WhateverYouWant();
```

Why can't you do the Skip() and Take() on the enumerable? Doing this will only download the results that are skipped or taken, the others won't be read.

**Edit:** The previous version was plain wrong in many aspects.

Comment: It is not what I'm looking for. When I put `ToList()` query executes, but it is too expensive to execute query without `Skip()`, `Take()`.

Comment: The AsEnumerable() solution should do the trick in this case (after edit)