# How to use table valued function in entity framework code first approach?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

i am working on a project using Entity Framework and now i got a situation where i need to use table valued function which returns table with 2 columns, hence i searched a lot and i came to know that we use table valued functions in Database first approach while i needed it in Code first.

here is the situation

i have a table with two columns

```
Table1

Id int PK
priority int
```

i want to use this table in my query in EF.

Is their any way i can use Table Valued function?

Comment: I got some help from this post but i am not sure if it works or not,  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-table-valued-functions-june-ctp.aspx

Answer (score 4):

We can do this by using the c# code generated by the CLR for Database first approach

you can refer this url for the full description 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-table-valued-functions-june-ctp.aspx

i had used this code and it worked fine for me

```
[EdmFunction("NorthwindEntities", "GetDetailsForOrder")]
public IQueryable<Order_Detail> GetDetailsForOrder(Nullable<global::System.Int32> oid)
{
ObjectParameter oidParameter;
if (oid.HasValue)
{
    oidParameter = new ObjectParameter("Oid", oid);
}
else
{
    oidParameter = new ObjectParameter("Oid", typeof(global::System.Int32));
}

return base.CreateQuery<Order_Detail>("[NorthwindEntities].[GetDetailsForOrder](@Oid)", oidParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I created a custom model convention which allows using store functions in CodeFirst in EF6.1. The convention is available on NuGet http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions. Here is the link to the blogpost containing all the details: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/04/09/support-for-store-functions-tvfs-and-stored-procs-in-entity-framework-6-1/