# TVF (Table Value Function) in entity framework using code-first

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, user-defined-functions

Does anyone know if it is possible to use TVFs in the entity framework using code-first? To be specific:

I know this is not supported for code-first currently (and it does not look like EF6 will allow it either). On the other hand, later versions of EF support TVFs in a database-first scenario (which is not an option for me). I am wondering if anyone know if there is some way to emulate what database first does by manipulating the model or something similar?

One further clarification; I know its possible to include TVFs by using SQL, but I also need the TVFs to be composable (i.e. be part of the entity LINQ statement).

Comment: In EF6, a very hacky workaround is to use an interceptor to rewrite an entity's table name to be a TVF call. I've made an [example implementation here](https://gist.github.com/sinelaw/9084984). **Not recommended!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use table valued function in entity framework code first approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769299/how-to-use-table-valued-function-in-entity-framework-code-first-approach)

Comment: This is now possible with EF6.1 and the custom convention I created. Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now possible. I created a custom model convention which allows using store functions in CodeFirst in EF6.1. The convention is available on NuGet http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions. Here is the link to the blogpost containing all the details: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/04/09/support-for-store-functions-tvfs-and-stored-procs-in-entity-framework-6-1/

Comment: Awesome work Pawel! I read your blog earlier today. I'm looking forward to trying it out next time we attempt to ditch the edmx files.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** currently possible. It was postponed until after EF6. The best thing to do is vote for it on their User Voice board. The feature suggestion is titled "[Code First support for Table-Valued Functions](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2686351-code-first-support-for-table-valued-functions)". I just put in 3 votes for it.

Comment: It's now possible - see my answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `Table-Valued Function` in Entity Framework 5.I think the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859577.aspx) will solve your question:

For using Table Value Function in Entity Framework you need to do the following steps:

**1.**  Right-click the project name in Solution Explorer, point to Add, and then click New
        Item.

**2.**  Select Data from the left menu and then select ADO.NET Entity Data Model in the 
        Templates pane.

**3.**  Enter `TVFModel.edmx` for the file name, and then click Add.

**4.**  In the Choose Model Contents dialog box, select Generate from database, and then 
        click Next.

**5.**  Click New Connection
        Enter `(localdb)\v11.0` in the Server name text box
        Enter School for the database name
        Click OK.

**6.**  In the Choose Your Database Objects dialog box, under the Tables node, select the
        Person, StudentGrade, and Course tables.

**7.**  Select the `GetStudentGradesForCourse` function located under the Stored Procedures 
        and Functions node Note, that starting with Visual Studio 2012, the Entity Designer
        allows you to batch import your Stored Procedures and Functions.

**8.**  Click Finish.

**9.**  The Entity Designer, which provides a design surface for editing your model, is
        displayed. All the objects that you selected in the Choose Your Database Objects
        dialog box are added to the model.

**10.** By default, the result shape of each imported stored procedure or function will
        automatically become a new complex type in your entity model. But we want to map 
        the results of the `GetStudentGradesForCourse` function to the StudentGrade entity: 
        Right-click the design surface and select Model Browser
        In Model Browser, select Function Imports, and then double-click the
        `GetStudentGradesForCourse` function
        In the Edit Function Import dialog box, select Entities and choose StudentGrade

You can use the following code to use `Table-Value Function` in the Application for retrieving data:

```
using (var context = new SchoolEntities())
{
    var CourseID = 4022;
    var Grade = 3.5M;

    // Return all the best students in the Microeconomics class.
    var students = from s in context.GetStudentGradesForCourse(CourseID)
                            where s.Grade >= Grade
                            select new
                            {
                                s.Person,
                                s.Course.Title
                            };

    foreach (var result in students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Couse: {0}, Student: {1} {2}",
            result.Title, 
            result.Person.FirstName, 
            result.Person.LastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Vaibhav, he is asking about "code first support". An .edmx file is "database first".